# error create site collection with template in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-foundation, site-collection, site-template

we had a web application which for each project create a site collection with a template in it. we had just one content database which uses it for all site collections in SharePoint 2007 we used the below command to create each web application

```
 stsadm -o gl-createsiteindb -url http://spsrv01:7000/tdd/205164
 -owneremail spsadmin@Test.com -ownerlogin medianet\spsadmin -secondaryemail spsiteadmin@Test.com  -secondarylogin medianet\spsiteadmin -sitetemplate "TDDCont" -title "Temp Project
 Data" -dbname TDD_ContentDB
```

but it does not work in SharePoint 2010 after upgrading from 2007 to 2010 and I get the below error is there any differences in `stsadm` command for SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2007 what should I do

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First be aware of the name after `-o` is the operation name and The error that you have got mean that this name is invalid or missing.

After long search, I found out that this `gl-createsiteindb` has been fixed to work with SP2 as mentioned at [recent-custom-stsadm-extensions-bug-fixes](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2009/07/recent-custom-stsadm-extensions-bug-fixes/)

He also introduces a workaround to do that as the following :

> Once you get the SPContentDatabase object you can simply use the Sites
>   property which returns an SPSiteCollection object and then call it’s
>   Add method to add the site to the database – seems so obvious now.

**I also advise you** to create a site collection with a custom template via the following script :

```
    $web = get-spweb https://sharepoint
$template = $web.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1033) | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq “<Custom Templete Title>”}
Write-Host $template.Name
New-SPWeb -Url “https://sharepoint/newsubsite” -Template “{D839E38A-F9DF-4B35-BDA7-A1E273C51EAB}#XXXX Template”

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
$web = get-spweb https://sharepoint
$template = $web.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1033) | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq “<Custom Templete Title>”}
$newweb = New-SPWeb -Url “https://sharepoint/newsubsite” 
$newweb.ApplyWebTemplate($template.Name)
```

- Check [CmdLet Ref](http://mstechtalk.com/create-sharepoint-site-spweb-using-custom-template-powershell/)
- Check also SharePoint 2010/2013: [Powershell to create SharePoint Site Collection with custom Template](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28770.sharepoint-20102013-powershell-to-create-sharepoint-site-collection-with-custom-template.aspx)